# How to check for document already in database before POST - MongoDB, NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to check to see if a document is already in the database before posting.  I am posting via a jQuery.post() method to my endpoint which is api/songs.

What I want to check is to see if the song is already in the database.  I can check that by querying the songId parameter that I am pushing to the database. If the song is already in the database I want to increment a number by 1.

What I have been trying to do is use mongo's findOne(), but I can't get it to work in the POST.  My post route looks like this:

```
router.post('/api/songs', function(req, res){

    if(Song.findOne({songId: req.body.songId}).length > -1){
        console.log('already in there fam')
    } else{
    var song = new Song();

    song.artistName = req.body.artistName;
    song.titleName = req.body.titleName;
    song.songId = req.body.songId;
    song.songImg = req.body.songImg;


    song.save(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error: " + err)
        } else {
            console.log("created fam")
        }
    })

    };
    console.log(song);
    return res.json({message: "SongCreated"})

})
```

My problem is that I can't figure out what the findOne is returning.  I want it to return a boolean so i've tried `count()` and `length()` but can't get it to return true.  The `req` posts to the DB no matter what.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All i/o operations in node.js are asynchronous. Your Song.findOne operation is asynchronous as well. You should wait for it to complete via callback functionality and then check the result of it.

Mongoose findOne method returns a promise. You can read more info about it [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html).

Example of promise execution:

```
var query = Song.findOne({songId: req.body.songId})
query.exec(function(err, song) {

})
```

Try the following code:

```
 router.post('/api/songs', function(req, res){
    Song.findOne({songId: req.body.songId}, function(err, song){
        if (err) {
            return console.log("Error: " + err)
        }
        if(song){
            return console.log('already in there fam')
        }
        var song = new Song();

        song.artistName = req.body.artistName;
        song.titleName = req.body.titleName;
        song.songId = req.body.songId;
        song.songImg = req.body.songImg;


        song.save(function(err) {
          if (err) {
            console.log("Error: " + err)
          } else {
            console.log("created fam")
          }
        })

        console.log(song);
        return res.json({message: "SongCreated"})
    })
})
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked to stop the duplicate from being put into the DB.  Now, if I want to modify the one that it found I take it that I shouldn't use `findOne()` and should instead use something like `findOneAndModify` correct?

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Yes, findOneAndModify is the better choice here because it will do it in atomic one query. You need to execute it and then check whether the record has been found and updated.